# Content-Transfer-Encoding vs Transfer-Encoding vs Content-Encoding

Tags: http, https, http-headers

I understand that `Transfer-Encoding` and `Content-Encoding` are similar except that one is "hop-by-hop" header, and the other is an "end-to-end" header. However, I'm confused at how `Content-Transfer-Encoding` relates to these. This header appears [here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/5_Content-Transfer-Encoding.html), but not in the [HTTP 1.1 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230), which leads me to believe it shouldn't be used anymore, but I don't see a replacement for it in the 1.1 spec. For example, what if I need to base64 encode the body content?

Also, assuming all three of these headers are given, what is the correct order of decoding to get the actual content as described by `Content-Type`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67929885/what-is-the-difference-between-content-transfer-encoding-and-content-type#comment120083025_67929885

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Content-Transfer-Encoding in HTTP, nor is there any need for it. In particular, there's no reason to base64-encode a message body.